# Stopping and restarting RAM-hungry python scripts, while saving data (linux)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have a python 2.7 script that takes various parameters. For any choice of parameters, a very large amount of RAM is needed, so that I can only run at most one instance of the script at a time.

I would like to have multiple instances with various sets of parameters taking turns every, say, 48 hours, and each time saving some data to the hard disk, so that they can resume later. In other words, let's say that I have two sets of parameters {x1, x2}, and {y1, y2} for which I want to take turns. I would like to achieve something like this:

```
while True:
    execute myscript.py x1, x2 
    sleep 48 hours
    tell myscript.py to stop and save a bunch of data to a file
    execute myscript.py y1, y2
    sleep 48 hours
    tell myscript.py to stop and save a bunch of data to a file
```

What should be the best approach here? I am using linux.

Comment: I hope that this is not a duplicate, but I couldn't find a solution for this, or I couldn't understand things enough to apply them in this situation.

Comment: Why the script eats so much RAM? Can't the algorithm be optimized to be less memory hungry so you don't have this problem in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep for sleeping

Comment: I am curious; can you tell us a bit more about what sort of problem / algorithm you are running? How much is "a very large amount" of RAM? Is this a per-problem data set, or reference tables, or ??  For such long runtimes, it may be worth coding some parts of the algorithm in Cython or C++. Also, by default Python only uses one processor core; with proper threading you could likely get a 4x or better speed-up.

Comment: Thank you very much @HughBothwell, but unfortunately It's too big a project to be discussed in the comment section. I am indeed working on cythoning it at the moment, but in the meanwhile I would like to get some results.

Comment: @Paulo, it is not a matter of optimizing; the sky is the limit for the amount of data I would like to have. So I would go as far as RAM permits me. That said, I am sure it can be optimized, but as I said earlier I want to get some results while I'm working on it..

Comment: I'm asking because in Python sometimes a small change to an algorithm can reduce memory footprint 2-3 orders of magnitude... I was wondering if this question suffers from the XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackless Python is the answer to this, as it can serialize a full python process at any given time & then restart it later.

http://www.stackless.com/wiki/Pickling

Comment: I think this is not going to work. I do not have root privilleges and I cannot install stackless python..

Comment: You don't need the former to do the latter. You need access to build-tools obviously. But if you can use cython, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I see.. I'll check with my administrator. Thanks!